# Backorder Notification Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I have a little problem with the backorder notification on my woocommerce shop.

What it is now: I set in the product backorders: allowed, but notify customer. When I press a variaton on the product page it will show available for backorder. So far so good. When someone place the order it will show the text backorderer: 1 on the order confirmation, on the pdf invoice, on the e-mail.

What I want: Show the notification only on the product information page. Not on the e-mails, order confirmation, etc. But when I set up backorders only to allow. There is also no notification on the Product Page for the customer.

So do someone of you know, how I can change this? Is there a custom code or something else I can use.

This is really important for me. I tried to find a solution about 1 week without any luck. So please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?
Just copy and paste this block of code to your functions.php file in your child theme.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'wcs_custom_get_availability', 1, 2); function wcs_custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) { // Change In Stock Text if ( $_product->is_in_stock() && ! $_product->backorders_allowed() ) { $availability['availability'] .= __('<br />Shipped immediately', 'custom'); } if ( $_product->is_in_stock() && $_product->backorders_allowed() ) { $availability['availability'] = __('<br />We will inform you via email when the product is back in stock. Please send us your contact info via the form below.', 'custom'); } // Change Out of Stock Text if ( ! $_product->is_in_stock() ) { $availability['availability'] .= __('<br />We will inform you via email when the product is back in stock. Please send us your contact info via the form below.', 'custom'); } return $availability; }
```

And let me know whether it worked for you or not.

Thank you

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)